# How to deploy Nuget package '.nupkg' to IIS

Tags: jenkins, iis, nuget, nuget-package, continuous-deployment

we are using NuGet command line( https://www.nuget.org/downloads ) to create deploy-able NuGet package (.nupkg).

The project is in .net framework 4.6, project is build using MSBuild & created the deployment package using Nuget.exe . We need to deploy the NuGet package(.nupkg) in IIS(Internet Information Services) on windows platform.

Tried to web-search but didn't worked out. need open-source tools or mannual automated step by step process to do so.

please guide.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/nuget-server

Comment: Is there any way available without Microsoft Visual Studio setup?

Comment: Read carefully the article and play with it. You just need VS to develop the web app, but once you are ready to deploy it on a real server, VS is no longer needed.

Comment: @Sanket Sawant, same requirement for me also. actually i am pushing the package into nexus repository through project package configuration. however i need to publish the uploaded package from nexus to iis using jenkins. i googeld lot but i can find the solution push the nupkg through jenkins only.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by "deploy the NuGet package(.nupkg) in IIS(Internet Information Services)"?

Anyway nupkg is just an archive so you can simply get dlls out of it with and use them where you need.

Comment: Okay. How we can deploy the MSBuild .net application to IIS with the continues integration?
We push .nupkg to Nexus repository and its available to all.
We require streamlining the process of Build and Deployable packages to Hosted servers.

Comment: did you found any solution